# Is anything interesting known about the number $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{M(n)}$ where $M(n)$ is the $n$th Dedekind number?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, lattice-orders

> **Question.** Is anything interesting known about the "Dedekind constant" $$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{M(n)},$$ where $M(n)$ is the $n$th [Dedekind number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_number#Summation_formula)?

*Motivation.* Given a sequence of positive real numbers $s$, define $\langle s \rangle$ to be the sum of reciprocals of the elements of $s$. $$\langle s \rangle := \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{s_n}$$ It's best to take the limit in $[0,\infty]$ so that sequences that grow too slowly have $\langle s \rangle$ equal to $\infty$. [Wikipedia has a page about the values of $\langle \Box \rangle$ for certain sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sums_of_reciprocals). Some familiar examples include $$\langle n \mapsto 2^n \rangle = 2, \qquad \langle n \mapsto n! \rangle = e, \qquad \zeta(s) = \langle n \mapsto (n+1)^s \rangle$$

Now, here's something interesting about the $2^n$ example: If $X$ is a finite set, then the bounded semilattice $FX$ freely generated by $X$ is isomorphic to the powerset lattice $(\mathcal{P}(X), \cup, \emptyset).$ Thus if $X$ has $n$ elements, then $FX$ has $2^n$ elements. So the sequence $n \mapsto 2^n$ arises from the concept "bounded semilattice" in a natural way.

Other choices of algebraic structure can also be used. However, one must be careful, because free algebras often have infinitely many elements. For example, the abelian group freely generated by $1$ or more elements is infinite. However, in some cases we end up with finite numbers. For example the concept "bounded distributive semilattice" has this property, and gives rise to the Dedekind numbers in the same way. It seems possible that the associated value of $\langle \Box \rangle$ is significant in some way or another.

Comment: ''It seems possible that the associated value ... is significant in some way or another.'' Anything is possible, but there's nothing here to justify or even  suggest this is anything other than a completely random constant.

Comment: @user670344, well, there's nothing here to justify the importance of this constant *in your opinion.* However, there's also nothing in your comment to justify or even suggest that your opinion is anything but a completely random guess :) In any event, my opinion is that the connection to free algebras renders this constant likely to be important in some way or another.

Comment: @user670344, also, note that from a decision-theoretic standpoint, this a good a question. Let $p$ denote the probability that interesting things are known about this constant, and $q$ denote the payoff associated with learning about such things. Then the payoff of asking this question is roughly $pq + (1-p)0$, where $0$ is an approximate description of the cost of asking the question. I believe the value of $p$ is quite high; you seem to think it's much closer to $0$. In both cases, $pq + (1-p)0$ is going to be strictly positive, unless $p$ is so close to $0$ that this model breaks down...

Comment: ... which I consider unlikely. This suggests that we can conclude with high certainty that this is a very good question to be asking, even if your guess at the value of $p$ is much lower than mine.

Comment: You seem to be missing a basic concept of mathematics: for something to be interesting, there has to be at least some actual idea. There are no ideas here, just a random construction made up on the flimsiest of analogies. Some experience leads one to understand that infinite sums $\sum a_n$ which have closed form expressions often do so for a number of definite reasons: they telescope, they are special values of analytic functions with good properties (expressible in terms of standard functions or integrals of such functions, or solutions to nice ODEs), and a few other very concrete reasons.

Comment: It's really just not the case that an interesting sequence $s_n$ should produce an interesting sum $\sum 1/s_n$ unless there is a particularly good reason to do so. There are no such reasons given here. You may has well have written you numbers in base $10$ and then concatenated the digits to form some decimal expansion and then asked about that.

Comment: It would be much more natural for a mathematician to rather ask questions (say) about the asymptotic behavior of $M(n)$ as $n$ increases --- or maybe to even consider the generating function $\sum M(n) x^n$ with $M(n)$ in the  **numerator**, which would be related to the question of how $M(n)$ is inductively related to $M(k)$ for smaller values of $k$.

Comment: @user670344, you seem to be missing the decision-theoretic justification for the question, which I explained at length...

Comment: Also, I disagree with the tone of your comments. You repeatedly emphasize that you think the actual $p$ value (as described above) given may be quite low with underhand and disparaging remarks like "flimsiest of analogies", yet offer no real arguments in favor of your particular opinion, just flimsy appeals to your own worldview. It's just so cringeworthy.

Comment: My mistake for interacting with an amateur on the cranky end of the spectrum. I'll leave you to your delusions. Apologies you don't like my "wordview" of actually knowing mathematics lol.

Comment: @user670344, *cringe*